# Files app (com.google.android.documentsui) keeps crashing

Tags: samsung, google, crashes

I have a Samsung S6 Lite and whenever I need to use the Files app as a FilePicker I get the message "Files has stopped". Specifically when trying to import a PDF in Squid Notes. However, this crash happens in any app that requires the default Files FilePicker.

Here is the following adb logcat filtered by Warnings and Errors (I had to use pastebin instead of posting the log here inline as StackExchange was detecting it as spam):

https://pastebin.com/raw/QaKP3FW2

```
18599 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.google.android.documentsui, PID: 18599
18599 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.documentsui/com.android.documentsui.picker.PickActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout$LayoutParams
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
18599 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout$LayoutParams
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.documentsui.NavigationViewManager.updateToolbar(NavigationViewManager.java:198)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.documentsui.NavigationViewManager.update(NavigationViewManager.java:154)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.documentsui.BaseActivity.refreshCurrentRootAndDirectory(BaseActivity.java:605)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.documentsui.AbstractActionHandler.loadRecent(AbstractActionHandler.java:838)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.documentsui.picker.ActionHandler.loadDefaultLocation(ActionHandler.java:236)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.documentsui.picker.ActionHandler.onLastAccessedStackLoaded(ActionHandler.java:190)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.documentsui.picker.ActionHandler.initLoadLastAccessedStack(ActionHandler.java:176)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.documentsui.picker.ActionHandler.initLocation(ActionHandler.java:135)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.documentsui.picker.PickActivity.onCreate(PickActivity.java:162)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
18599 E AndroidRuntime:     ... 11 more
 5189 W ActivityManager: crash : com.google.android.documentsui,0
```

The crash also happens when the device is booted in Safe Mode. I'm new to Android and have some developer/coding experience, unfortunately I have no experience with Java to interpret what the error means.

I did disable/uninstall some Samsung bloatware from the tablet the previous night, but was using Squid Notes and importing PDFs and using the Files app just fine after the fact. It seems the problem started happening once I powered the device off and back on. My gut tells me I messed something up uninstalling things I didn't think I'd use, but I have since reinstalled and re-enabled everything I disabled and rebooted the device, but the crash persists.

Hopefully someone can see what might be causing the crash, as I'd like like to try and fix it without having to factory reset the device if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have rooted your device you should not be able to make system modifications that could cause this. The main error is `com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout$LayoutParams` which means some theming class has changed and does not match the expected class. Usually this is a bug in the app but we are talking about a system app and your device is old and should not get updates anymore. Therefore this bug should not appear out of nowhere...

Comment: I have not rooted the device at all. I have since found out that you can do an "Uninstall updates" in the App Settings. After doing so and rebooting the device the Files app opened once without a crash, but now it's crashing again. My device is the Samsung S6 Lite tablet which came out in the last year, so it's not old

Comment: Okay, so it seems the Files app auto updated shortly after I used the old version after rebooting, so that's why it was crashing again. The version without any updates is "q_release_aml_patch_291602100" and the newest version that's crashing is "r_aml_301500700". I'm not sure how I can keep it from auto updating since the app isn't technically on the Google Play Store. When disabling auto updates in the store, and then checking for updates, the Files app doesn't even show up as needing an update after I revert it to it's old version.

Comment: Then open the app every day a few times (and let it crash) and hope that the crash report is also sent to Google so that they recognize the problem and fix it soon